# Define return values for a function that is not of type Boolean

Tags: functions, options, symbols

I have a function with *more than two* possible return values.

A simplified example is the following function that classifies vertices of a graph according to their degrees:

```
VertexRole[g_, v_] := Which[
  VertexDegree[g, v] == 1, BadVertex,
  VertexDegree[g, v] == 2, MediocreVertex,
  VertexDegree[g, v] == 3, GoodVertex
  ]
```

However, defining the function in this way would be bad practice since the symbols `BadVertex` etc. are undefined. Furthermore, I want to evaluate expressions such as

```
VertexRole[graph, vertex] == BadVertex
```

Defining `BadVertex` to be a number (e.g. 42) would also be bad since I actually want

```
BadVertex == x
```

to evaluate to `False` for *all* `x` other than `BadVertex`.

Therefore `BadVertex` etc. should be symbols similar to `True`, `False`, `Automatic`, `All`, `None`. How can I implement that?

[One could use a string as the return value (e.g. `"BadVertex"`), but that kind of misses the syntactical point I am trying to make. I am rather looking for something that resembles the enum type in C.]

Comment: Why do you think using undefined symbols is a bad practice?

Comment: Why not output a string or some number that encodes your desired output if you insist on not making new symbols?

Comment: @happyfish Because undefined symbols are not `Protected`.

Comment: @Deniz No, user defined symbols are not protected unless you do it manually. You can also protect a undefined symbol, if you are referring undefined as not having own values, down values , etc.

Comment: @Deniz Why do you think it is a problem that they are not protected?  You can simply not assign values to them, or if you are worried that this might happen by accident, then protect them.  Also, use `===` for comparison.  I think in the end that's the only thing you need: `===` vs `==`.

Comment: It would help if you could phrase the question in terms of an actual problem.  Using symbols for this is good practice in my opinion.

Comment: Rather than repeated evaluation of `VertexDegree[g, v]` you might want to consider using [Switch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks reasonable to me. If I were doing this, I would

- manually [`Protect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protect.html) those symbols on the off chance that for some reason I accidentally assigned them values (though this is not necessary for them to work),
- assign them `::usage` messages so they register correctly into the system (and therefore display in black instead of blue, and
- use `===` (i.e. [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)) instead of `==` (i.e. [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) if I wanted to make it very explicit that "`BadVertex == x` should evaluate to `False` for all `x` other than `BadVertex`".

If you're really worried about it, it would also be acceptable to use strings instead of symbols, but really it looks fine as is.

Comment: One might sometimes consider using `MatchQ[]` instead of `===`, but that depends on the application.